# jQuery - order html table rows dynamically, not using ui-sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm trying to make a controllable html table list.

My List is like that:

```
<table>
    <tr id="selection_18">
        <td>
            <select id="colors_18">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="selection_27">
        <td>
            <select id="colors_27">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="selection_5">
        <td>
            <select id="colors_5">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button onclick="orderRows();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Scenario is like that: user select all colors for example;

for first row he selected red, for second row he selected yellow, for third row he selected again red, ... and for ninetieth row he selected yellow.

And user wants to order all rows by color again to see for example which color is selected how many times.

What should i write in javascript function `orderRows()`. I can use jQuery but not want to use jQuery UI sortable. Because in some of my list, it has 400 rows. I think it would be not good solution.

Comment: not order colors, order rows by selected color val in row

Comment: it isn't important. I wanna make rows like red,red,red,yellow,yellow,yellow instead of red,yellow,red,red,yellow,red. Red can be first or last, it doesn't matter...

Comment: @AndroCoder you can do that with a simple code. You can use your existing table, no need to use external hashmap for rendering table. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this;

```
$("#order").on("click", function() {
    $('tr').sort(function(a, b){
      return $(a).find("option:selected").text() > $(b).find("option:selected").text();
    }).appendTo('table')    
});

$("#order").appendTo("table"); // this is for keep button place
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/nzJrd/)**

In demo, you can select colors, and click order button. After order, you can select your colors again and click order to shuffle.

**Note:** `a`, and `b` in function refers to specific two elements `n` and `n+1` for each iteration. It means, it is comparing nth and (n+1)th element for each iteration. If n > n+1 element, n remains same, if not, n+1 moves place before n

Comment: Hüseyin çok teşekkür :) yalnız sort olayının a sı b si nedir ben onu çözemedim. Bir dökümantasyon var mıdır

Comment: Türk mü çıktın :) a sı b si şu demek. elinde 3 eleman var x, y, z. İlk iterasyonda a = x, b = y  ikinci iterasyonda a = y , b = z oluyor.  Yani hep n ile n+1 karşılaştırıp hangisi büyükse bir üste taşıyorsun. Just for incoming users see detail about `a` and `b` in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The function below will build a hashmap that groups the IDs of the select elements based on the color selected. You could use that hashmap to render the table however you would like to.

See the working demo at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X95HG/1/)

JS:

```
function orderRows(){
    var colorArray = [ 'All', 'Red', 'Yellow' ];
    var colorMap = {};
    $('table select').each(function(){
        var color = colorArray[$(this).val()];
        if( colorMap[color] == undefined ){
            colorMap[color] = [];   
        }
        colorMap[color].push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('div#display').html(JSON.stringify(colorMap));
}
```

HTML added (notice that the button was pulled out of the table):

```
<div>
    <button onclick="orderRows()">orderRows</button>
</div>
<div id="display">
</div>
```

JSON displayed example:

```
{"Red":["colors_18","colors_5"],"Yellow":["colors_27"]}
```

Comment: how can i render table by using this hashmap

Comment: You have JSON that groups the IDs by the selected color. Iterate through the JSON and "order" the items. Not 100% clear on what you are trying to do when you said "order rows".

Comment: in the example default order of trs is: selection_18 > selection_27 > selection_5. User selects for colors_18 red, for colors_27 yellow, for colors_5 red. Then press button. I'm trying to see table like selection_18 > selection_5 > selection_27 .

Comment: SO, you'd like to re-shuffle the table based on the selected color?